# How to filter in Django-graphene?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, graphene-python

I use graphene-Django to build a GraphQL API. I have successfully created this API, but I can't pass an argument to filter my response. I want to filter with the forging key from my model.

model.py:

```
class TodoList(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    text = models.TextField()
```

schema.py:

```
class TodoView(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = TodoList
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'date', 'text')
        

class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User

class TodoQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    todoList = DjangoListField(TodoView)

    def resolve_all_todo(root, info):
        return TodoList.objects.filter(userId=2)
```

But when I do filter it show all object in the result

When I send this request:

```
{
  todoList {
    id
    title
    date
    text
  }
}
```

I've got this response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "todoList": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "test",
        "date": "2021-09-13",
        "text": "test todo"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "test2",
        "date": "2021-09-13",
        "text": "test2"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "admin2 test",
        "date": "2021-09-13",
        "text": "admin2 test"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "admin2 test2",
        "date": "2021-09-14",
        "text": "admin2 test2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I have missed? Or maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: I believe the resolver should be named "resolve_<type>" and in your case "resolve_ todoList"

Answer (score 1):

You have two options,

1. Change the resolver method's name to ***`resolve_todoList(...)`*** from *`resolve_all_todo(...)`*

```
class TodoQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    todoList = DjangoListField(TodoView)

    def resolve_todoList(root, info):
        return TodoList.objects.filter(userId=2)
```

2. Use the **`resolver`** argument to specify your resolver method

```
class TodoQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    todoList = DjangoListField(TodoView, resolver="resolve_all_todo")

    def resolve_all_todo(root, info):
        return TodoList.objects.filter(userId=2)
```